# How to rewrite URL in Web.config

Tags: .htaccess, azure, web-config, web.config-transform

My URL is http://merzent.com/love/index.php?u=48

I want to change it like http://merzent.com/love/48

I can do this using htaccess but my app is running in Windows Azure. So, I think I need to do this using web.config and I'm new for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871717/how-do-you-configure-windows-azure-for-url-rewrite-using-wordpress

Comment: You're welcome, mark the question as solved if your issue has been resolved ;)