# How to configure Azure to always show index.html

Tags: angularjs, azure, url-routing, angular-routing

I am hosting a web application on Azure - I deployed it yesterday by just copying all the required files into wwwroot. 
It sort of works - except that it behaves differently than when it did when I just ran npm start locally (it's an Angular 2 app, with config copied from the [5 min quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)) - when I ran it locally, I could manually enter any URL which was handled by routers and it did load, and on Azure it throws a 404 (also happens when I just refresh any page besides the home page) - I presume that somehow when I ran it locally, it figured out that I always need to load index.html, regardless of the actual URL, and let the router handle everything. How can I replicate this behavior on Azure?

Comment: I would help if you'd specify the Azure service you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Azure WebApp is running on an IIS instance by default.
If you want to handle the Html5 Mode(without the hashbang) then you have to create a `Web.Config` file and define a rewrite.

See [How do I configure IIS for URL Rewriting an AngularJS application in HTML5 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode)

Dont forget to set `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` of your index.html. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: Thank you, one of the responses (Josh C's one) there helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will probably have to use URL Rewrite for this, unless you are using MVC to deliver the page. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871717/how-do-you-configure-windows-azure-for-url-rewrite-using-wordpress) is a previous answer that will help you configure URL Rewrite. It is talking about WordPress, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should try checking the Azure portal under the Application Settings for the Web Application if .index.html is included in the List of Default Document option
I would be glad if you can rephrase your Question to understand it more.